# GDB skips over my code!

Tags: c++, gdb

So, I've defined a class like

```
DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver
{
DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver()
:   // initializer list
{
    // stuff
}

//  ... other functions here

};
```

In main, I instantiate DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver like so:

```
int main()
{
    // ... run stuff
    Sensor sensor(port, timer);

    DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver dlss();

    Log::notice("started");
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I step through this code in gdb, it runs:

```
Sensor sensor(port, timer);
```

skips

```
DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver dlss();
```

and continues with

```
Log::notice("started");
```

What gives?

---

**EDIT:**  By changing

```
DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver dlss();
```

to

```
DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver dlss;
```

in main(), the line executes.  Can someone explain why?

Comment: just to be sure: are you using `-g` to compile your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver dlss();
```

does not declare an automatic variable.  It declares a function named `dlss` that takes no arguments and returns a `DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver`.

You want:

```
DataLoggingSystemStateReceiver dlss;
```

The object will be default initialized, so for your class type, the default constructor will be called.

Comment: Is this behavior occuring because the object's default constructor takes no arguments?

Comment: @sheep: No. This is just a shortcoming of the syntax, it's called the "most vexing parse". The compiler simply reads this as the declaration of a function, it has nothing to do with your class.