# GDB not breaking on breakpoints set on object creation in C++

Tags: c++, gdb

I've got a c++ app, with the following main.cpp:

```
1:  #include <stdio.h>
2:  #include "HeatMap.h"
3:  #include <iostream>
4:
5:  int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
6:  {
7:    HeatMap heatMap();
8:    printf("message");
9:    return 0;
10: }
```

Everything compiles without errors, I'm using gdb (*GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1346) (Fri Sep 18 20:40:51 UTC 2009)*), and compiled the app with gcc (*gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)*) with the commands "-c -g".

When I add breakpoints to lines 7, 8, and 9, and run gdb, I get the following...

```
(gdb) break main.cpp:7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10000177f: file src/main.cpp, line 8.
(gdb) break main.cpp:8
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x10000177f.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x10000177f: file src/main.cpp, line 8.
(gdb) break main.cpp:9
Breakpoint 3 at 0x100001790: file src/main.cpp, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /DevProjects/DataManager/build/DataManager 
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++. done

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff960) at src/main.cpp:8
8       printf("message");
(gdb)
```

So, why of why, does anyone know, why my app does not break on the breakpoints for the  object creation, but does break on the printf line?

Drew J. Sonne.

**EDIT**: Answer - [GDB skips over my code!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579020/gdb-skips-over-my-code/2579044#2579044)

Comment: We had a question about this very topic earlier today:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579020/gdb-skips-over-my-code/2579044#2579044 (exact duplicate).

Comment: I did search for gdb, breakpoints, etc, but couldn't find it, but thanks this provides more info.

Comment: That's okay, search can be wonky. Your question introduces more keywords into the mix, helping future searchers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate HeatMap as:

```
HeatMap heatMap;
```

`HeatMap heatMap();` declares a function that returns HeatMap.

Comment: @Drew - you're definitely not stupid.  You have run into the oddity of C++ syntax that is known as "the most vexing parse".